# Exception guarrantees vs 2013 push_back

Tags: exception, c++11, vector, visual-studio-2013, stl

Is there bug in VS2013 STL implementation because in following code when vector reallocate object it use move constructor instead copy constructor?
 I try on gcc 4.8 and it works as I expected. When I add noexpect to move constructor program produce the same output(use move constructor when reallocation make place).

Exception safety of [vector::push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) is documented on [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com):

`If a reallocation happens, the strong guarantee is also given if the type of the elements is        either copyable or no-throw moveable.`

Following move constructor don't guarantee no-throw.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Movable {
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    Movable() {

    }

    Movable(const Movable& other) {
        name = other.name;
        std::cout << "Copy constructor Movable" << std::endl;
    }

    Movable(Movable&& other) /*noexcept*/ {
        std::cout << "Move constructor Movable" << std::endl;
        name = std::move(other.name);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Movable> vec;
    Movable moved;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vec.push_back(moved);
    }
}
```

Comment: VS doesn't support `noexcept`, so it can't do any checks based on that.

Comment: Ok but any way, without noexcept it should call copy constructor.